# DistinctAsync for MongoDB C# driver throws Cannot deserialize a 'List<String>' from BsonType 'String'

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document that has a list of string Tags. I am looking for all the distinct Tags across the collection to be returned as a list of string.

```
 public class TestGetDistinctDocument 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

I can achieve this for other fields using `Distinct` and `DistinctAsync` as such

```
                var result = collection.Distinct(doc => doc.Name, FilterDefinition<TestGetDistinctDocument>.Empty);
                return await result.ToListAsync();
```

Which returns a list of all distinct "Name" in the collection. But doing the same with Tags throws

`System.FormatException : Cannot deserialize a 'List<String>' from BsonType 'String'.`

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
                var cursor =  await collection.DistinctAsync(doc => doc.Tags, filter);
                var distinctTags = await cursor.ToListAsync();
                return distinctTags.SelectMany(tag => tag).ToList();
```

I am using mongo-csharp-driver version 2.8

Comment: can you show the records of this collection? maybe you have a string value on the tags field instead of an array.

Comment: Tags is definitely an array, I made sure of that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to achieve this

Use `FieldDefinition` to define the field you want to "Distinct" on as such

`FieldDefinition<TestGetDistinctDocument, string> field = "Tags";` instead of using Linq as use

```
 var filter = FilterDefinition<TestGetDistinctDocument>.Empty;
 FieldDefinition<TestGetDistinctDocument, string> field = "Tags";
```

And then use `DistinctAsyc` or `Distinct` with this passed in the parameter

```
                var cursor =  collection.DistinctAsync(field, FilterDefinition<TestGetDistinctDocument>.Empty);
                return await cursor.Result.ToListAsync();
```

This gives a list of distinct Tags across all TestGetDistinctDocument.